# ios: addAnnotations to mapView not working

Tags: ios, mkmapview

Hi I have a NSMutableArray with annotation objects the follwoing code will not add the annotation:

In .h I have

```
     @property (retain, nonatomic) MarketsDataController *marketList;
```

In .m I have (Adding annotations does not work. Nothing shows up on Map)

```
    _marketList = [_marketService.marketsDataController retain];
    NSLog(@"%@!!!", [_marketList objectInListAtIndex:0].title);
    [mapView addAnnotation:[_marketList objectInListAtIndex:0]];
    [mapView addAnnotation:[_marketList objectInListAtIndex:1]];
    [mapView addAnnotation:[_marketList objectInListAtIndex:2]];
```

MarketsListDataController looks like this:

```
    #import "MarketsDataController.h"

    //The following interface is used for private methods
    @interface MarketsDataController ()
    - (void)initializeMarketsList;
    @end

    @implementation MarketsDataController

    //Set initial values for instance variables
    - (id)init {
        NSLog(@"init MarketsDataController");
        if (self = [super init]) {
            [self initializeMarketsList];
            return self;
        }
        return nil;
    }

    - (void)initializeMarketsList{
        NSMutableArray *marketsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Initialize the product list
        _marketsList = marketsList;                      //Set the markets list to the markets list
    }

    //Return the number of products
    - (NSUInteger)countOfList {
        return [_marketsList count];
    }

    //Return a product within the list
    - (MapAnnotation *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex {
        return [_marketsList objectAtIndex:theIndex];
    }

    - (void)addAnnotationToList:(MapAnnotation *)mapAnnotation{
        NSLog(@"Adding market");
        [_marketsList addObject:mapAnnotation];
    }

    - (void)dealloc {
        NSLog(@"DEALLOC MarketsDataController");
        [_marketsList release];
        [super dealloc];

    }

    @end
```

MapAnnotation .m looks like:

```
#import "MapAnnotation.h"

@implementation MapAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle;

- (id)init{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = 0;
    location.longitude = 0;
    return [self initWithCoordinate:coordinate title:nil subtitle:nil];
}

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c title:(NSString *)t subtitle:(NSString *)st{
    self = [super init];
    coordinate = c;
    title = [t retain];
    subtitle = [st retain];
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc{
    [title release];
    [subtitle release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I create them and add them in another class like:

```
if (![latitude isEqual:[NSNull null]] && ![longitude isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
                     NSLog(@"%d", i);
                    NSLog(@"%@", title);
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
                    coordinate.longitude = [latitude doubleValue];
                    coordinate.longitude = [longitude doubleValue];
                    [self buildMarketsList:coordinate title:title subtitle:@""]; //build the browse list product

                }
```

The method is below:

```
- (void)buildMarketsList:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c title:(NSString *)t subtitle:(NSString *)st{
    MapAnnotation *mapAnnotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc]initWithCoordinate:c title:t subtitle:st];
    [_marketsDataController addAnnotationToList:mapAnnotation];
    [mapAnnotation release];
}
```

How can I add an array of annotation objects that implement < MKAnnotation > ? I get no errors and No annotations will show.

Comment: _marketsList is of type NSMutableArray ? How will this work _marketList.marketsList? And also _ prefixed variables are adviced to use only in setters .

Comment: why you keep _marketList.marketsList?

Comment: _marketsList is an object that has an NSMutable array that holds annotation objects.

Comment: @Eli Miller What is your question?

Comment: see edit in main post

Comment: What do  you mean by this .. "_marketsList.marketList"

Comment: Have you connected your mapview object to the mapview on screen via an IBOutlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem:

change:

```
                coordinate.longitude = [latitude doubleValue];
                coordinate.longitude = [longitude doubleValue];
```

To:

```
                coordinate.latitude = [latitude doubleValue];
                coordinate.longitude = [longitude doubleValue];
```

Comment: I just saw this, and thought.. lol, what a silly mistake, I'm sure that won't be my cause.. *checks* and it was.... *face palm* Cheers ell :)

Answer (score 0):

_marketsList is not an object with an array. It *is* an array.

If you have a property called `marketsList` that is backed by variable called _marketsList

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * marketsList; //in your .h


@synthesize marketsList = _marketsList; //in your .m
```

then you should do something like this:

```
- (void)initializeMarketsList{
    marketsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Initialize the product list

    [marketsList addObject:myAnnotation];//ad some annotations
}
```

and then add your array of annotations to the map view

```
[mapView addAnnotations:marketsList];
```